# AngularJS : Binding an input with variable made variable undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I am new to AngularJS, and I have a problem with ng-model.

Here's my code:

```
<section class="field row" ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <input class="value" ng-show="editMode" placeholder="{{field.name}}" ng-model="field.value" type="url" />   
</section>
```

As you can see, I'm looping through `$scope.fields` which I got from the server and is an array of about 40 objects that have keys like `name` and `value`.

Inside the section I have an input, which has the `ng-model` property set to `field.value`. When the server gives a value to the field, it is shown inside the input.
At some point I want to update the user's changes, by sending $scope.fields back to the server.

However, when the user changes something in the inputs, the `value` for the changes fields becomes `undefined`.

I hope this describes my problem well enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this caused a problem is simply because the input was a URL input and I was typing simple "hello" strings to test it, instead of typing URLS. Apparently AngulaeJS only puts the answer in the model if it matches the field type.

Answer (score 0):

To get the changes, you should pass the original object name i.e fields. Refer below calling fn
    ng-click="save(fields)"